# TestFlight questions popup not appearing

Tags: ios, testflight

The TestFlight SDK documentation says all you have to do in order to add a modal questions screen to your app is to add the question via the web interface and associate it with a checkpoint that's already in your app. I did this a couple days ago, but have still yet to see a questions popup appear. Has anyone else used the TestFlight questions interface before? Am I missing a step?

Comment: I am having this problem as well, there support is a bit slow.

Comment: Have you followed all of the steps under the "Integration" heading at: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/1.1/ ?

Comment: Yes, I have followed all of those steps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but their support team told me that my problem is a bug in their platform about the version number. If you upload a build many times with the same version number, they will put a "#" near version, this is the problem, the sdk don't show questions correctly in build with "#" version. To fix the problem you should upload a build with new version number or delete the old one before upload new build.